# Comparing forward and reverse loop for int with one limit as 0

Tags: c++, loops

Consider the example with `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= NUM; i++);  // forward
for(int i = NUM; i >= 0; i--);  // reverse
```

I tested this loops with gcc (linux-64). Without any optimization flag, forward loop was faster and with optimization to O3/O4, reverse loop was faster.

Somewhere I heard that due to **better cache replacement techniques**, forward loop is faster.

Personally I think, reverse loop should be faster (whether NUM is a constant or variable). Because any microprocessor will have single instruction for comparison with 0, `i >= 0` (i.e. `JLZ (jump if less than zero)` and equivalent).

Is there any deterministic answer to this ?

Comment: linux-64 = x86_64 or ia64 or alpha64 or sparc64?

Comment: One word: Micro-optimization. The difference surely doesn't matter enough for anyone to care.

Comment: Out of interest does pre-increment or pre-decrement change your observation here?

Comment: @Cody - if the intent is to learn more about the hardware rather than prematurely optimise then the question is potentially quite interesting

Comment: Did you look at the emitted assembler code?

Comment: @awoodland: Clearly that's not the intent. The question says *nothing at all* about hardware.

Comment: btw, every i386 processor and above had a single instruction for comparing 2 numbers (jg, jge..) and actually, jz in intel assembly means to jump if the zero flag is on, and that only means last computation returned zero. In intel there is no special jump for zero.

Comment: @Danish94 - The DEC instruction will also set the zero flag if the result happens to be zero. Then you could skip the CMP instruction and go directly to JZ/JNZ. Potentially saves you half a nanosecond :-)

Comment: @all the machie is little old. **Kernel 2.6.9-55.ELsmp on an x86_64**. my intent is to learn that how huge loops (which are called frequently) can be optimized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is absolutely *no* deterministic answer for this. You're looking at two different levels of abstraction.

C++ has absolutely *nothing* to say about what happens under the covers, performance-wise. It specifies a virtual machine which executes C++ code and, while it covers functionality, it does not cover performance of the underlying environment <sup>(a)</sup>.

Which of those is faster will depend on a variety of factors. You may find yourself running on a CPU which makes no distinction between comparing with an arbitrary value and comparing with zero.

You may find an architecture where incrementing a register is ten times faster than decrementing one, bizarre though that may seem.

You may even find a brain-dead architecture that has no decrement, add or subtract instructions at all, and you have to emulate decrement by calling increment 2<sup>n</sup>-1 times (where `n` is the word size).

Bottom line: you can't presume to know what's going on under the hood unless you want to look at a very specific CPU, compiler, etc.

You should optimise your code for readability first. If you need to process things in an increasing manner, use the first option. If a decreasing manner, use the latter. If either way seems equally natural, then choose the fastest one, discovered by benchmarking or analysis of the underlying architecture and assembler code. But *only* do this if you have a *specific* performance problem, otherwise you're wasting effort.

In any case, since you're almost certainly going to be *using* `i` for something, it's likely that whatever tiny increase in performance you get by going the fastest way will be more than swamped by the fact that you now have to calculate `NUM-i` inside the loop (unless, of course, the compiler is smarter than the developer which, based on what I've seen from `gcc`, is quite possible).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It does specify *certain* performance-related things such as the time complexity of some things in the containers library, but not specifically the thing you're asking about, whether forward loops or reverse ones are faster.

Answer (score 1):

The cache replacement techniques only come in effect if there is a conflict. Perhaps `NUM` isn't big enough for it to have an effect, or perhaps the mapping of virtual to physical memory happens to be favorable for the cache replacement algorithm.

Trying to potentially save a single machine instruction is showing lack of trust for the compiler. If it was that easy, surely the optimizer would know that!

Comment: agree with the `lack of trust` part. But I was curious to know about the underlying things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe incrementing a loop variable is so much more common that CPU's branch prediction works better on those.

With the compiler optimization, you loop might be just unrolled—given that I correctly assume, your `NUM` is a `#define` constant—and therefore faster.

Comment: if you `#define` a constant integer in C++, I'll have your scalp, really!

Comment: I don't, I was just guessing from the capitalization. But anyhow that's not the point. I meant if the compiler knows, the variable won't ever change, it might unroll the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't really answer your question, but a thought. How about this loop:

```
int  i = NUM + 1;
while ( i --> 0 )//it looks as if i goes to zero (like in calculus)!
{
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour if `NUM == INT_MAX` ;-p